# How to trick compiler to optimize memory reading?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I heard about compiler optimizations.

For example the one when:

```
while(myBool)
    doStuff();
```

compiler knows you do not modify myBool inside a while loop, it just read myBool once and doesn't check it every time.

This can be affected by `volatile` keyword right?

So I have tried to "trick" compiler, it thinks value was not changed.

```
int main()
{
    struct st 
    {
        int a;
        int b; //I want to make difference by writing volatile here
    }s;

    s.b = 1;

    while(s.b > 0)
    {
        *((&s.a)+1) = 0;
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But even with full optimizations turned on (vs2012), this does not trick the compiler. This is probably very lame trick :)

How can I trick it? Is it even possible?

My goal is to create simple single-threaded program, which prints "test" with `volatile` keyword used and prints infinite-times "test" without the keyword.

EDIT: Unfortunately I am not good with assembler, so I really can not read if the memory reading was optimized out in the first place :)

Comment: Trying to get rid of doing one comparison between an int and 0 each iteration sounds like a premature optimization. How much time will this actually save?

Comment: The point is he wants to trick the compiler into doing the optimization when it shouldn't.  He's not trying to save time.

Comment: This isn't java.  You don't have to trick the compiler into doing things.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to have the compiler make an optimization (in this case, not re-read a variable) when it should have? Is this not the same as saying you want to find a bug in the compiler?

Comment: @GManNickG: Not necessarily a compiler bug. Invoking undefined behaviour could also work, without it being a compiler bug.

Comment: On intel, true `volatile` variables are reloaded on every access IIRC.  I'm not sure what it will get you...

Comment: @Grizzly: That's *true*, but it's also a bit silly. If OP is fine with UB, then concluding "the compiler was tricked" is a rather empty statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is undefined behavior.  You can't access `s.b` by writing to `*((&s.a)+1)` instead since there's no guarantee that `s.a` and `s.b` don't have any padding bytes between them.

If you want to force there to be no padding, look into your compiler options.  For GCC/Clang, you'd declare the structure with [`__attribute__((packed))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).  For MSVC, you'd use the [`#pragma pack` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

There's no good reason to be accessing `s.b` through `s.a` using that code.  What you should really do in this case, assuming you have a good reason for not accessing `s.b` directly, is use an array (`volatile`, if need be).  Arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory without needing special attributes/pragmas.

Furthermore, the compiler won't make certain optimizations in some cases: if `i` is a variable and you write to `a[i]` followed by a read of `a[1]`, the compiler can't assume that `a[1]` wasn't just written to, so it won't be able to cache it in a register.  Whereas if you have two unrelated variables `a` and `b` and you write to `*(&a+1)` and then read from `b`, the compiler *will* assume that `b` was not just written to.  That's one very good reason why `*(&a+1)` is undefined behavior, since it leads the compiler to make untrue assumptions and cause your program to behave in strange ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to make sure that the compiler assumes the value is almost the same (in your example true) so the compliler optimizes for this value.
If you do then your are looking for a compiler specific set of keywords.
This is what I use in g++

```
#define predict_true__(exp)     __builtin_expect((exp), 1)
#define predict_true__(exp)       (exp)
```

This way you can do

```
while ( predict_true__( myBool ))
    doStuff() ;
```

It will be running efficiently for myBool is true.
Hope it helps and you will know what to look in case of visual you use.

Addition: I have found the following post which talks about it. I am afraid it is a sad talk, though: [likely/unlikely equivalent for MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440570/likely-unlikely-equivalent-for-msvc)

Comment: That should only change the (static) branch prediction, not change the behaviour of the application (introduce a bug) if `myBool` is not actually `true`. For processors with good branch prediction it won't even make a performance difference for any branch called often enough to matter

Comment: @chris: thanks for pointing it out. That is what we use at the office. I will pass information down to the people here to change __predict_true() to predict_true__() instead. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `structs` are not guarenteed to be contiguous in memory. Arrays are. You can not access the struct like that!

A SO question that may be of help: [Pointer arithmetic for structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623704/pointer-arithmetic-for-structs). It goes into a little more detail about how you can not do this and why. But a summary is that there may or may not be padding between the fields of the struct. I particularly like Charlie's answer on that question.